# Second order differential equation particular solution of a product

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I read that when the right side $f(x) = e^x$, a suggested form of $y_{ps}$ is $Ce^x$, and for $f(x)$ is linear in $x$, a form of $y_{ps}$ is $Cx + D$. If $f(x)$ is the product of the two mentioned, then the form of $y_{ps}$ is also the product of their particular solutions. [Source](http://www.reading.ac.uk/AcaDepts/sp/PPLATO/imp/h-tutorials/ode_08_2ndOrdinhomog.pdf).

I'm working on the following example, and having trouble finding the particular solution:
$$ y'' - y' -2y = (2x-1)e^x $$

If I understood correctly, I could treat this problem as two parts: 
$$ y'' - y' -2y = (2x-1) $$
and 
$$ y'' - y' -2y = e^x $$
Then find the particular solutions for both of them, then multiply the particular solutions, would that be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use $y_p=(Ax+B)e^x$
Expand it you'll get $Axe^x+Be^x$ Then find the first and second derivatives and plug them into the original funtion

Comment: Thanks! Worked out as it should!

Comment: Quick question,if on the left hand side, the y-term is missing, do you multiply $y_p$ with an additional $x$ in that case? So for example, if I have the following: $$ y'' - 2y' = (x^2 + x -3)e^{2x} $$, would $y_p = (Ax^3+ Bx^2 + Cx)e^{2x}$? Or $(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^{2x}$?